# What's the reason that my property is undefined in the .ts file but the .html file works

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I got an angular app which is loading data from an external server.
My sessions are loaded perfectly and I can use them via property binding in the `HTML-view`, but whenever I try (for example) the commented line about the `imgurl`, my sessions-properties is `undefined`. Anyone knows what's causing this or how I could resolve this.

```
export class SessionsComponent implements OnInit {
  public sessions : ISession[] = [];
  public ImgUrl : any;

  constructor(private sessionService : SessionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getSessions();
    // this.ImgUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.sessions[0].sessionPhoto.image.data;
    // console.log(this.sessions[0].session_name);
  }

   getSessions() {
    this.sessionService.getSessions().subscribe(
      data => {this.sessions = data},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('sessions loaded')
      
    );
```

Comment: `getSession()` is async, so the data is not available yet when you try to use it in your ngOnInit. You should move that logic within the subscribe callback

Comment: Because you're trying to get an unresolved value before `getSessions()` promise gets resolved. You should use `observable` in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getSessions` method run async meaning it isn't finished by the time you try to access it. A quick fix could be to move your commented code inside the `getSessions` method like this:

```
getSessions() {
    this.sessionService.getSessions().subscribe(
      data => {
          this.sessions = data;
          this.ImgUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + this.sessions[0].sessionPhoto.image.data;
          console.log(this.sessions[0].session_name);
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('sessions loaded')
    );
}
```